# Does anyone know a JSON, JS Array parser in Java and/or PHP?

Tags: java, php, json, parsing

I need a JSON, JS Array parser in Java and/or PHP. Do you know any parser ?

regards,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[json.org](http://json.org) lists a whole slew of them for both languages.

The java one is here: http://www.json.org/java/index.html

[PHP 5.2](http://www.php.net/releases/5_2_0.php) has it bundled already.

Answer (score 5):

PHP can decode JSON objects already... use [`json_decode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

```
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';
var_dump(json_decode($json));
```

Comment: And a JavaScript array. Something like [["apples", "fruit", "red"], 
["broccoli", "vegetable", "green"], ["cherries","fruit", "red"]] ?

Comment: **@Arthur Ronald F D Garcia:** No problem, `json_decode()` will work as well for that JSON string.

Answer (score 1):

json_decode() and json_encode() will do the trick, as long as your text is UTF-8.

Comment: Does it work fine in ISO-8859-1 ?

Comment: **@Arthur Ronald F D Garcia:** you can always `utf8_encode()` your string before passing it to `json_decode()`.

Comment: Anyway, ISO-8859-1 can be somewhat considered as a subset of UTF-8. You won't have any problems using `json_decode()`. Problems might arise if you are using `json_encode()` though on a ISO-8859-1 website.

Answer (score 1):

[FlexJson](http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/) is not too bad for Java, it even allows for typing of the JSON.  I didn't really like the json.org Java libs serialization, it required a lot of coding.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP >= 5.2, you can use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) (as said in other answers).

In PHP 5.1.x, I have successfully used [`Zend_Json`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.json.html) both to encode and decode JSON data -- it does not require the whole Zend Framework to work (If I remember correctly, it requires `Zend_Exception`, and that's it)